Incorrectly registered broadcast receiver (play.google Publish Overview, issue keeps showing)
I'm kinda stuck on why the publish overview still reports this error

when all of the registerReceivers are already modified to avoid the violation. Since my versions are configured to,
Target: 34
Compiled: 34
Minimum: 24 

I used the ContextCompat function, in all places in the project that has a block of code for receiver registration.
ContextCompat.registerReceiver(
      requireContext(),
      broadcastReceiver,
      IntentFilter(INTENT_FILTER),
      ContextCompat.RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED
) 

I searched throughout the project and the only thing I found with a receiver not having an exported flag is a manifest declaration from leakcanary which is coming from non-production merged manifests, also leakcanary is used as debugImplementation only,
<receiver android:name="leakcanary.internal.NotificationReceiver" />

Any help would be appreciated.

You want to explain why you're using notifications in your app's privacy policy site. In my instance, I am utilizing foreground service, hence the same problem exists. I specified in the privacy policy how to handle music play and pause, as well as a link to video recording, to explain.

Is it working by your method. You added just suitable privacy policy right ?

yes , with recorded video proof of notification of why i am using in my app.

Probably issue was solved.
but
the reason of this can be the libraries you are using in the project. (warning from google play console doesn't contain a place where issue was found)

This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient reputation you will be able to comment on any post; instead, provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker. - From Review
